# IE9/8 Form issue

Tags: forms, internet-explorer-9

I am having issues with a form in IE9 and IE8.

I have put the code into JS Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/EV3N5/) and it comes up with the error '< / FORM >' in red.

```
<FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">
    <p>Window Width
        <br />
        <input name="inputWidth" />
    </p>
    <p>Window Height
        <br />
        <input name="inputHeight" />
    </p>
    <p>Glass Thickness
        <br />
        <input name="inputGlass" />
    </p>
    <p>Sash Density
        <br />
        <input name="inputDensity" />
    </p>
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="Submit" onClick="testResults(this.form)">
</FORM>
```

Could someone go over it and point out my stupid mistake?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The red form is because the input tag is not closed:

```
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="Submit" onClick="testResults(this.form)">
```

To

```
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="Submit" onClick="testResults(this.form)"/>
```

As to why it is not working in IE, you need to be more specific about what is not working.

Comment: Thanks for that. IE9 and 8 are just making the entire page except for the header go white.

Comment: I'm not extremely familiar with IE, but you can try adding `type="text"` to the inputs just incase that is the problem although it should work fine either way.  Otherwise, you can look at the developer tools for IE and see if there are any erroneous pieces.

Comment: I tried that. But still having the same issue. For a second, it will display the entire, then it goes white (same colour as the background). I took out the FORM tags and it will load, but then it's useless. So I think there is an error in my FORM.

Comment: You could try putting everything except obviously values and names in lowercase letters since that seems to be the only difference between the form and the inputs but other than that, the code should be working properly.